# NextJS deployment on Azure

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have been doing mostly with Vue and basic React before (which is not recommended anymore) and now I have problems in deploying this on Azure.

The base problem is the basic NextJS build does not include index file at all. Also, it generates pages to the `.next` directory when I visit on them, not in the build.

So I tried export which was great for my purpose and all the pages are generates, but it is not supporting these:

- i18n in route
- Rewrites

I can handle those two problems. I need `rewrite` just in development situation when I call endpoints in my locally driven backend and `i18n` locale string can be moved away from route. Problem is `API routes`, or I just think they are the problem. I am not using NextJS own APIs or created any apis to api directory. I am using axios for API calls in self created requests directory and graphql in self created qraphql directory.

**Question is**: If I do build with `next export`, is the app still able to call endpoints with `axios`? My graphql is using `react-query` and would this work too?

Comment: Yes. Your app will still be able to make requests against your API.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks! Can you make that comment as an answer so I can mark it as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is still able to make requests against the API. API Routes is a way to create rest API using Next.js.